# RabbitMQ - deliver unacked messages to a different queue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ for my messaging system.

I want to make sure that whenever I have unacknowledged messages (during consumption), the messages won't return to the same queue (as the consumer disposes), but will be sent to a different queue in order to prevent a loaded queue.

I know that I can configure policies for mirroring, but I don't think that it helps me to fulfill this kind of a requirement.

Does anybody know how to handle this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Setup [Dead Letter Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and use `basic.reject` or `basic.nack` to put message to it.
 You may also find useful [Alternate Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) and [TTL Extension](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).